# #define statement explanation

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I was going through a code given to me by my teacher and I came across this:

```
#define setBit(var, bitnum)   (var)|=(1<<(bitnum))
#define resBit(var, bitnum)   (var)&=~(1<<(bitnum))
#define ROW_RESET       setBit(PORTA,4) ; resBit(PORTA,4)
```

The first two `#define` statement are self explanatory but I am having problem understanding the third one. Is the third statement (line) right? Can we write statements after  semi-colon(;), if yes then please can you explain what is happening here.

Comment: the third one is very buggy. as soon as you see style like this, you run.

Comment: Argh, this is what your teacher wrote? Really he shouldn't this is really bad code. Macros that hide statements should always be with `()` to make the call resemble to a function call. Multiple statements in one macro should be encapsulated by the `do { ... } while(0)` trick such that they don't result in surprising control flow when put in a different context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Semicolons may be used in macro definitions, and will simply have the effect of making the macro expand to multiple statements:

```
ROW_RESET;
```

will expand to

```
setBit(PORTA,4) ; resBit(PORTA,4);
```

It is also allowable to use e.g. block statements with curly braces in macro definitions, as long as the result after expansion is syntactically valid (at the point where it is expanded).

As usual, the more "fancy" stuff you do in a macro, the more easy it is to get it wrong - for example, if you have a function with the signature `void foo(int)`, you could call `foo(setBit(PORTA, 4))`, but `foo(ROW_RESET)` would not compile, as it would expand to `foo(setBit(PORTA,4) ; resBit(PORTA,4))` (which is illegal because you can't have semicolons inside a function call).

Comment: Should there be another semicolon at the end of the third statement or the statement as it is, is correct?

Comment: That would allow for the expression `ROW_RESET` to compile without a trailing semicolon, which would look confusing when reading the code - so I'd recommend not adding a trailing semicolon to the macro, thus forcing you to write `ROW_RESET;` when you use the macro.

Comment: Also, see Jens Gustedt's comment on your question, which suggests more ways to make this macro better and safer.

Answer (score 0):

A more experienced C programmer would make them like this:

```
#define setBit(var, bitnum)   ((var)|=(1<<(bitnum)))
#define resBit(var, bitnum)   ((var)&=~(1<<(bitnum)))
#define ROW_RESET do { setBit(PORTA,4); resBit(PORTA,4); } while (0)
```

...and then, I'd go check that PORTA was defined as a simple constant and not some expression with possible side effects.

As for what the macro does, it's quite simple: it sets a bit to one, then sets the same bit to zero. This is probably an embedded system like an Atmel chip with some memory-mapped I/O at that address connected to something that triggers on a rising edge, and can handle a pulse smaller than the clock rate of the processor.